# Mini Magick, GraphicMagick and Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, carrierwave, image-uploading, minimagick

I am trying to get my uploader file to resize images as they are uploaded using the following code:

```
 version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_limit => [230, 230]
 end
```

I have installed Carrierwave to handle the upload along with GraphicMagick to process the images (installed correctly) and MiniMagick (installed successfully using `gem install Mini_magick`)

I keep receiving the following error though:

`No such file or directory - identify -ping C:/Users/THOMAS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mini_magick20120904-4644-1jvulye.jpg`

```
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"yzrsjbr91do/8kpk7R67A7MMNfHu+6+BRQlTlBfPssw=",
"profile"=>{"name"=>"test2",
"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x4946e68 
@original_filename="centaur.JPG",
@content_type="image/jpeg",
@headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profile[image]\";  filename=\"centaur.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
@tempfile=#<File:C:/Users/THOMAS~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20120904-4644-4abl14>>}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

I managed to get this working on another windows 7 computer but for whatever reason I keep receiving this error.

If anyone could point me in the right direction to fix this it really would be much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

try require 'mini_gmagick' instead of require 'mini_magick', graphics magick has only one executable gm, and by default mini_magick uses image magick, which has multiple binaries and identify is one of them.